# how to connect to a server after opening a .sql script in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, connect, ssms

in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I use `File -> Open -> File (Ctrl + o)` to open a .sql script, which includes a list of select statements. However, when I try to run them it complains that it's not connected to any server. What should I do?

Usually I right click a server in the Object Explorer panel (to the left) and select `New Query`. But that will open a new tab. In theory I could then copy-paste the codes from the previously opened .sql file to the new tab. But that's not what I'm looking for.

Thx!

Comment: use File --> Connect Object Explorer

Comment: or there is a Connect button within the Object Explorer anel itself that will do the same thing.  p.s. this is probably not an StackOverflow question.  Probably better suited for SuperUser but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get there. One is to right-click inside the query window, then choose Connection -> Change Connection...

Comment: no it is all greyed out it is nonsense I have a database connection. A script is a script, not a connection. MS SQL is F***ed

Answer (score 2):

File -> Open -> File with New Connection is one way